# In .NET 6 MVC - view is 404 not found unless I manually change the file type to "content" each time

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

In .NET 6 MVC - view is 404 not found unless I manually change the Build Action from "none" to "Content" each time. Is that normal? Surely Visual Studio should automatically know that the .cshtml files are content, but by default they are created as "none".

[image]

**Update:**
In my .csproj it has added the file three times:

`<Content Remove="Views\Home\Test2.cshtml" />`

`<Watch Remove="Views\Home\Test2.cshtml" />`

`<None Include="Views\Home\Test2.cshtml" />`

I can't see any kind of default or folder level settings in the csproj which could affect this.

Comment: how are you creating the files? and what Visual studio version are you using? I don't have this behavior, the view file build action is content when I added them

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows (latest update - 17.2.5) and simply right clicking the folder and choosing Add > View. Then properties shows them as "none" straight away.

Comment: what does your csproj file look like. I think cshtml by default file have content. unless it is changed in csproj like this
    <None Include="Views\Home\Test2.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Home\Test2.cshtml" />

Comment: Yeah it's done exactly that. I have updated the main post with more info.

Comment: Does this happen in any newly created project? or specific project?

Comment: I just tried it in another project and same behaviour.

Comment: However on a NEW project it's fine! Something must be different about these older projects (likely upgraded from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now fixed this by creating a new .csproj and copying in the project references and package references only, then restarting Visual Studio.  There must have been something in the  entries causing this issue.  I suspect it was this line:

`<Watch Include="**\*.cshtml" Exclude="node_modules\**\*;**\*.js.map;obj\**\*;bin\**\*" />`

...but removing that line on it's own caused VS to not recognise any changes to cshtml files.

Comment: Had the exact same thing happen to me. It's definitely that line of code, not sure how to get around it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the line and then fully restarting VS?

Comment: Yes. If I don't include that line, the build action none problem goes away but I can't get hot reloading to work with .cshtml files. If I leave the line on the build action none problem occurs, but hot reloading works. Just don't know how to get both working properly?

Comment: Try what I put in my answer above. It fixed it for me.

Comment: So you no longer use  <Watch Include="**\*.cshtml" Exclude="node_modules\**\*;**\*.js.map;obj\**\*;bin\**\*" /> ?

Comment: No I don't use that line - because if you create a new project from scratch it doesn't seem to be there. I'm assuming it's left there from a previous version of .NET or even going back to when I used Razor.RuntimeCompilation instead of Hot Reload.   It doesn't seem to be needed in new projects.

Comment: Interesting, I can't get hot reloading for .cshtml files to work unless that line is in there. Not sure what I can do to eliminate it

Comment: I finally fixed the error, I was adding a library called NToastNotify that was using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation below 6.0.5 which causes .cshtml files to stop working in hotreload

Comment: You shouldn't need Razor.RuntimeCompilation at all if you're using Hot Reload - it conflicts! Did you upgrade the package version or just remove it?

Comment: I updated the NToastNotify library to use a higher package 6.0.9 and it seemed to work. Ideally maybe I could just remove it?